# how to use KeyScan from ConnectionMultiplexer in stackexchange.redi

Tags: .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have following code for redis connection

```
 private static readonly Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> Conn = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(
            () =>
            {
                try
                {

                    if (ConfigOptions != null && ConfigOptions.Value != null)
                    {
                        return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(ConfigOptions.Value);
                    }
                    return null;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.Fatal(ex.Message, ex);
                    return null;
                }
            });

        private static ConnectionMultiplexer Muxer => Conn.Value;

        public static bool KeyExists(string key)
        {
            var result = false;
            try
            {
                IDatabase getDatabase;
                if (Muxer != null && (getDatabase = Muxer.GetDatabase()) != null)
                {
                    result = getDatabase.KeyExists(key);
//https://riptutorial.com/stackexchange-redis/topic/66/scan  
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Fatal(ex.Message, ex);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Key command is expensive command
Any idea how can i use scan command which is implemented in stackexcahnge implementation as

public IEnumerable Keys(int database = 0, RedisValue pattern = default(RedisValue), int pageSize = CursorUtils.DefaultPageSize, long cursor = CursorUtils.Origin, int pageOffset = 0, CommandFlags flags = CommandFlags.None)

From **Muxer** object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stackexchange.Redis will use SCAN inside its Keys implementation (if Redis version is >=2.8). Making it safe on the Redis side as it be a non-blocking operation.

Still, you should make sure your app can handle the large reply. The SCAN iterations are internal to Stackexchange and you cannot add your logic on each iteration.

You should read about it more [here](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/KeysScan.html).